# "message": "java.lang.NullPointerException" when trying to insert entity via api-explorer

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-api-client, google-cloud-endpoints

I`m new in appEngine and i trying simple things that are necessary for my project:
I create simple JDO class of Image:

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class Image {

@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
private Key key;

@Persistent
private Blob image;

@Persistent
private String type;

@Persistent
private String description;

public Key getKey() {
    return key;
}

public void setKey(Key key) {
    this.key = key;
}

public Blob getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(URL url) throws IOException {

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                url.openStream()));

        String line;
        StringBuffer stbf = new StringBuffer();

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            stbf.append(line);
        }
        image = new Blob(stbf.toString().getBytes());
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

End-Points where succesfully created and deplyoed to AppEngine.
When i trying to insert simple object to datastore via google-api-explorer
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?base=https://my-application.appspot.com/_ah/api#s/, 
with just link to image and Key with id and appID paraemeters, i recieve the following error:

```
503 Service Unavailable

- Show headers -

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "backendError",
    "message": "java.lang.NullPointerException"
   }
  ],
  "code": 503,
  "message": "java.lang.NullPointerException"
 }
}
```

When i changing key to by from type Long, query executed properly and i see new entity in datastore.

Additional to that, in Documentation said that "If the encoded key field is null, the field is populated with a system-generated key when the object is saved". But seems that it`s not accept it without key?

Can anybody help me with this issue?

Comment: I take it that you're using Endpoints since you're accessing your page via the Explorer? Can you post the rest of your JDO class, plus the code for your Endpoint class?

Comment: this is the whole jdo class.

Comment: Can you post the Endpoints class then? It's the class with the @Api annotation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the generated method containsImage:

The standard generated code doesn't check if getKey() returns null. You'll need to include something like:

```
if (image.getKey() == null) {
            return false;
}
```

before it does a getObjectById.

Comment: It appears that this bug is now fixed, and the generated code includes this test.

Comment: It hasn't been fixed yet. Updated the whole appengine stack for eclipse today. The problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to fix this for a while. The suggested answer is correct. I thought to add a note: this is NOT fixed in the GAE SDK or Eclipse plugin. I.e. null keys are still not checked. Thanks for the tip! Sorry I could not add a comment, don't know why.